# DataOutputStream keeps giving a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

So I have tried using my code with `DataInputStream` and `BufferedReader`
to send a String from a Client to a Server and have looked up resources all over the Internet for a solution to this. I am using a method that reads in a String from Client and it ALWAYS shows a NullPointerException every time. Here is a copy of the code on the Server side:

```
package WOF;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TheBoard {

    private int port;
    Socket client;

    public TheBoard(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void start() throws IOException 
    {
            System.out.println("Now Determining if guess is correct");

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            sendWelcomeMessage(client); 
    }
    private void sendWelcomeMessage(Socket client) throws IOException
    {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes("Hello, You are now Playing Wheel of Fortune, Command Line Style!!");
    }
    public void getGuess(Socket client) throws IOException
    {
        String userInput;
        DataInputStream getGuessFromClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream()); //NPE Occurs Right on this Line.
        System.out.println(getGuessFromClient);
        userInput = getGuessFromClient.readUTF();
        System.out.println("Guess is: " + userInput);
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int portNumber = 9990;
        try 
        {
            TheBoard socketServer = new TheBoard(portNumber);
            socketServer.start();
            socketServer.getGuess(socketServer.client); //This Throws an NPE
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("UH OH!! Can't Connect.." + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I commented in the code where the stacktrace occurs and have done a lot of my own troubleshooting but can't seem to get past the line that creates getGuessFromClient. I'm sure this is a trivial solution but my research has come up empty handed. Does anyone have any suggestions?

By the way, here is the stacktrace:

```
Now Determining if guess is correct
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at WOF.TheBoard.getGuess(TheBoard.java:40)
    at WOF.TheBoard.main(TheBoard.java:52)
```

Comment: your `client` is null.

Comment: you are using class variable `client` in your main where as in your `start` method `client` is not initialized rather you created new local variable `client`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I know what a Null Pointer Exception is, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
```

Use:

```
client = serverSocket.accept();
```

You are assigning the client to a local variable, rather than the member variable, so you are currently not assigning the member variable before you dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared "client" variable twice :

1. Inside TheBoard class
2. Inside start() method.Which is nothing but a local variable.

But you should use same instance variable inside start() method. So instead of :

```
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
```

write

```
client = serverSocket.accept();
```

inside start() method.